# org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaSession i large when related session is small

Tags: session, attributes, memoryanalyzer

We have a two-nodes application, meaning there are two Tomcat servers, with same application on each of them. And there is one database.

Every logged user has it's own UserSession object, which attributes (session attributes) are "evened" between those two nodes by org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaSession.

We checked with JavaMelody, that the UserSession objects are small - about 30 KB. But releted to them DelataSession objects are many times larger - they are from several MB to one hundred dozen MB.

We expect that DeltaSession is no larger then related to it UserSession object.

Are there known any common isuues, which are the cause of "swelling" of DeltaSession object?